# Update a field between all records of the same Object

Tags: apex, trigger

how could I create a trigger on a custom objects that Updates a field for all of the custom object records with a shared OpportunityId

Opportunity->Demo(Notes field in the Demo to be updated for all Demos that share the same OpportunityId, so the content on notes will sync between all of them.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the standard [Aggregate Query Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) for this. You'll also want a trigger handler to avoid unnecessary recursion.

```
trigger updateNotes on Demo__c (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    DemoTriggerHandler.execute(Trigger.new);
}

----

public class DemoTriggerHandler {
    static Boolean isRecursive = false;
    public static void execute(Demo__c[] triggerNew) {
        if(isRecursive) {
            return;
        }
        Map<Id, Demo__c[]> demos = new Map<Id, Demo__c[]>();
        Demo__c[] updates = new Demo__c[0];
        // Aggregate
        for(Demo__c demoRecord: triggerNew) {
            demos.put(demoRecord.Opportunity__c, new Demo__c[0]);
        }
        switch on Trigger.operation {
            when BEFORE_INSERT, BEFORE_UPDATE {
                // Get prefixes from old demo notes
                for(Demo__c demoRecord: triggerNew) {
                    demos.get(demoRecord.Opportunity__c).add(demoRecord);
                }
                for(Demo__c demoRecord: [
                        SELECT Notes__c, Opportunity__c
                        FROM Demo__c
                        WHERE Opportunity__c = :demos.keySet() AND
                            Id != :triggerNew]) {
                    for(Demo newDemoRecord: demos.get(demoRecord.Opportunity__c)) {
                        newDemoRecord.Notes__c = newDemoRecord.Notes__c.removeStart(demoRecord.Notes__c);
                        newDemoRecord.Notes__c = demoRecord.Notes__c + '\n\n' + newDemoRecord.Notes__c;
                    }
                }
            }
            when AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE {
                // Query
                for(Demo__c demoRecord: [
                        SELECT Notes__c, Oppportunity__c 
                        FROM Demo__c 
                        WHERE Opportunity__c = :demos.keySet() AND
                            Id != :triggerNew]) {
                    demos.get(demoRecord.Opportunity__c).add(demoRecord);
                }
                // Update
                for(Demo__c demoRecord: triggerNew) {
                    for(Demo__c relatedDemoRecord: demos.get(demoRecord.Opportunity__c)) {
                        if(demoRecord.Notes__c != relatedDemoRecord.Notes__c) {
                            relatedDemoRecord.Notes__c = demoRecord.Notes__c;
                            updates.add(relatedDemoRecord);
                        }
                    }
                }
                isRecursive = true;
                update updates;
                isRecursive = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
This is exactly what I needed. 
One question on the trigger call, I'm getting this error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void execute(List<Demo__c>, List<Demo__c>) from the type DemoTriggerHandler

I have never used a handler for Triggers, not sure what I have to add for the trigger method.

Comment: @Franco Actually, I changed the method half-way through writing this, so I forgot to update the trigger code. See my revision.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! It is working now.
One issue tho, when I insert a new Demo, the Note info gets lost for all previous Demo Notes.  Is there a way to attach at the end the info they put in the last created Demo instead of deleting the previous notes for all?

Comment: @Franco Sure, that's a little more complicated, but not by much. The new edit should take care of this. That said, this is getting to the point where I'm not sure this is best solution. Why not add a Report/Visualforce Page/Web Component to just show the combined notes of all Demos?

Comment: Thank you, Fox!
The main issue is that we need to send the field to one of the systems we have connected  to Salesforce. Say, we get to a 3rd demo of our product, they can see all of the feedback on all of them. It is in fact a mess, but I can see this helping our users